# How to hide a hyperlink control inside gridview through code behind inside page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a  gridview on my web form. I have taken a hyperlink control inside the template field of gridview. I want that this hyperlink should be visible to only site admin. I have done this through *Gridview_RowDataBound* property. But instead of doing this I want to hide this hyperlink within page load.

This is what I have done so far.

aspx page-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1"
BorderStyle="None" EnableModelValidation="True" ShowHeader="False" Width="1000px" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
                        ForeColor="#FF3300" CommandName="EDT" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","test1.aspx?id={0}") %>'>HyLink</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

cs page-

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(Session["logname"]) != "Admin")
            {
                HyperLink Hlnk = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink2") as HyperLink;
                Hlnk.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do this within page load? Please guide.

Comment: Why you want on Page_Load?

Comment: @Adil: Actually I placed a checkbox within my gridview. And I have written some codes within the checked property of the checkbox based on certain condition. So, when I was using Gridview_RowDataBound() property, the checked property was not working.
So I removed it. And then previously I was hiding this hyperlink control through RowDataBound property. That is I wanted a solution for doing it somehow through pageload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        HyperLink myHyperLink = row.FindControl("HyperLink2") as HyperLink;
        myHyperLink.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
  HyperLink myHyperLink = (HyperLink)gvExcParts.Rows[i].FindControl("HyperLink2");
  myHyperLink.Visible = false;
 }
```

but make sure bind data to gride view then find controls inside it, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: Hello Ehsan, it is not working. I can see this hyperlink button even from different user apart from Admin.

Comment: I want to do this within page load.

Comment: Actually since, I was not using Rowdatabound property and directly writing this code in the page load. Then later on I placed this code after calling Gridview.DataBind(). And then the problem was solved.

Comment: yes before databind it will not be able to finde because data is not binded

Comment: Exactly. So that is what I was doing wrong. But corrected it finally. Thanks to u again :-)
Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this after after DataBind to GridView...

```
GridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
```